# Keep alive for just one particular route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is there any way to restrict keep-alive to only one specific route?

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view

This keeps all the routes in memory:

```
<keep-alive>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </keep-alive>
```

I’d like only one of my particular routes to be kept in memory, not all of them. Can I define keep-alive another way? Possibly define it within the routed component itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try v-if on the keep-alive element.

Comment: Can you explain further?  I don't see how that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use props to manage keep-alive:

**include** - Only components with matching names will be cached.

**exclude** - Any component with a matching name will not be cached.

more: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html#keep-alive